# Facebook - show a help dialog

Tags: php, facebook

How can I show a typical facebook modal help dialog when the user clicks on one of the links on my Facebook app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using an IFrame app, you can use FB.UI.PopupDialog from the JS API. The bad news is that there is zero documentation for this feature, and it isn't very easy to use. The good news is that I've already figured it out! :)

```
// First, define the HTML content you want in the dialog as a javascript string:
var content = '<div><h2>Help is here!</h2><div>Hint: you can eat the cookies!</div></div>';

// Then add the content to this resource dictionary thing, wrapped in a div with the id "RES_ID[your identifier here]"
FB.UI.DomResources.addResourceDict(new FB.UI.DomResDict('<div id="RES_IDhelp01">' + content + '</div>'));

// Instantiate the popup dialog and show it:
var popup = new FB.UI.PopupDialog('Help?!', FB.UI.DomResources.getResourceById('help01'), false, false);
popup.show();
```

Of course, these bits can be spread out through your page as required, and you can use php to generate the html content for you.

Easy, right? :D Enjoy!

Comment: Please don't ask how long it took me to figure this out. It wasn't pretty.

Comment: <div id="RES_IDhelp01"> should be <div id="RES_ID_help01"> from my testing

Comment: Oh well... it had a good run. I'm surprised it worked for this long considering how frequently Facebook changes things.

Answer (score 0):

Codebliss' link led me to a documentation page showing me how to invoke an iframe popup dialog within your webpage using their [JS SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.ui/). You first have to load the Facebook script:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({appId: '[YOUR_APP_ID]', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
 </script>
```

Then put something like in your page:

```
<a href="#" id="test">click me</a>
// some code
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').click(function() {
    FB.ui({
      method: 'feed',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      link: '[YOUR_WEBSITES_REGISTERED_URL_ON_FB]',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
      message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
    },
    function(response) {
      if (response && response.post_id) {
        alert('Post was published.');
      } else {
        alert('Post was not published.');
      }
    });
  });
});
```